# Android Daily Notification setRepeating Spamming

Tags: service, notifications, alarmmanager, spam

I'm trying to implement a notification service in Android which is triggered daily buy the alarmmanager. I read, that the method of the alarmmanager `setRepeating()` have changed from API 18 to API 19. So you should use `setExact()` now. 
I'm currently implement on API 18. So this shouldn't affect me. I use `setRepeating()` and the first time the notification gets fired is at the right time. But then it is going crazy :D The notifications keep getting fired randomly. Sometimes 3 times after another and then 2 days nothing.

My Code:
First time my App is being started the following lines will be executed:

```
private void startAlarm(){
   Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

   calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
   calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
   calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 7);
   calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
   calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

   Intent myIntent = new Intent(this , NotifyService.class);
   AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
   pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myIntent, 0);
   alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, pendingIntent);
}
```

My NotifyService Class looks like this:

```
public class NotifyService extends Service {

 private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

 @Override
 public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
 }

 @Override
 public void onCreate(){
    Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationManager mNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent1, 0);

    Notification mNotify = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(text)
            .setContentText(text)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.pic)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setSound(sound)
            .build();

    mNM.notify(1, mNotify);
 }
}
```

The relevant Imports are:

```
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
```

I also tried using `setExact` with API 19 and calling setExact everytime my notification gets fired, but with no success.

No one has any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone is looking for an Answer to my Question:
Here is what I have done and what worked.

You need to stop the Service you created. So in my NotifyService Class right below

```
mNM.notify(1, mNotify);
```

add this call:

```
stopSelf();
```

This worked for me.

Edit:
If you want the Notifications appear even if the device was shut down, you nee to add an Boot_Completed Receiver.

So your Receiver Class:

```
public class BootCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

      startAlarm(); // See Method above (in Question)

   }
}
```

And in your Manifest add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

and

```
 <receiver
        android:name="package.BootCompleteReceiver"
        android:process=":remote" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```